# When is $\zeta(s)=0$?

Tags: riemann-zeta, constants

At what real constant does $\zeta(s)=0$? Does that constant have any significance? Thank you very much for any help provided.

Comment: This comment supplements Faraone’s answer. It’s conjectured that not only do the non-trivial zeros of $ \zeta $ lie within a critical strip, they actually lie on the critical line $ \left\{ \dfrac{1}{2} + i t ~ \middle| ~ t \in \Bbb{R} \right\} $. This is the famous Riemann Hypothesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All real zeroes of the Riemann Zeta function (also called the trivial zeroes) are of the form:

$$x=-2n$$

Where $n\in \Bbb N_0$

All the other zeroes are supposed to lie on a critical strip in the Complex Plane.

Comment: Note that $\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: In fact I said that $n\in \Bbb N_0$ and not $n\in \Bbb N$ @Neves

Comment: $\mathbb{N}_0=\{0, 1, 2, \cdots\}$...

Comment: Well no... @Neves $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ while $\Bbb N_0=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ , $\Bbb N_1=\{0,2,3,\dots\}$ and so on...

Comment: Please see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) under the section Notation, or [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Natural_Numbers).

Comment: @Neves I'm so sorry, in Italy we use notation as I mentioned, never came in this kind of controversy.